# JavaScript on click event handler

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Есть проблема в следующем коде: скрипт не работает.

Цель - при нажатии на "click here" спрятать login div и перекинуть юзера на login helper.

Буду рад любой критики и лучшим примерам!

```js
function loginHelper(){

     document.getElementById("pass_forgot").onclick = function (){ 

     document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("login_help").style.display = "block";
    
    }
}
```

```html
 
<div id = "login" class = "login_form">

 <form id = "logger">
  
  <label for id = "user_name">User name:</label>
  <input id = "user_name" name = "user_name" type = "text" placeholder = "user name">
  <br>
  <label for id = "password">Password:</label>
  <input id = "password" name = "password" type = "text" placeholder = "password">
  <br>
  <label for id = "email">Email:</label>
  <input id = "email" name = "email" type = "email" placeholder = "email">
  <br>
  <label for = "remember_me">Remember you on this computer ? </label>
  <input type = "checkbox" name = "remember_me" id = "remember_me">
  <br>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Login">

 </form>

<p id = "pass_forgot">Forgot your password? <a href="#login_help"> <button onclick = "loginHelper()">Click here!</button></a></p>


<div id  = "login_help" class = "login_help">

  <form id = "helper">
  <label for id = "email">Your current email:</label>
  <input id = "email" name = "email" type = "email" placeholder = "email">
  <br>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Send">
  </form>

  </div>
```

Comment: что есть "перекинуть юзера на login helper"?

Comment: Не понял вопроса .. что конкретизировать ?

Comment: Зачем у Вас кнопка внутри линка?

Comment: Не понимаю как это связанно с моим вопросом.. Решил поставить для красоты.. уверен что проблема не в этом.. пробовал и без..

Comment: так сформулируйте проблему, или ее надо угадать?

Comment: Я же написал  - скрипт не работает , спс за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function loginHelper(){

 //    document.getElementById("pass_forgot").onclick = function (){ 

     document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("login_help").style.display = "block";
    
 //   }
}
```

```html
<div id = "login" class = "login_form">

 <form id = "logger">
  
  <label for id = "user_name">User name:</label>
  <input id = "user_name" name = "user_name" type = "text" placeholder = "user name">
  <br>
  <label for id = "password">Password:</label>
  <input id = "password" name = "password" type = "text" placeholder = "password">
  <br>
  <label for id = "email">Email:</label>
  <input id = "email" name = "email" type = "email" placeholder = "email">
  <br>
  <label for = "remember_me">Remember you on this computer ? </label>
  <input type = "checkbox" name = "remember_me" id = "remember_me">
  <br>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Login">

 </form>

<p id = "pass_forgot">Forgot your password? <a href="#login_help"> <button onclick = "loginHelper()">Click here!</button></a></p>
  
  </div>


<div id  = "login_help" class = "login_help" style="display:none;">

  <form id = "helper">
  <label for id = "email">Your current email:</label>
  <input id = "email" name = "email" type = "email" placeholder = "email">
  <br>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Send">
  </form>

  </div>
```

Comment: да, скорей всего:
1. ТС забыл закрыть один див
2. Прятать не login, a logger (т.е. саму форму)